# How to make regex stop at a certain character

Tags: javascript, regex

I need match the following path

```
var path = '/posts/type/my-type';
```

to the following route:

```
var route = '/posts/type/:type';
```

In order to do that, firstly, I make the `route` variable a regular expression:

```
var regroute = route.replace(/\:[a-zA-Z]+/, '(.*)');
```

and then create a regular expression out of it:

```
var regexp = new RegExp('^' + regroute + '\/?$');
```

When I match the path to route, the matching works. However, it has a problem with not stopping matching when it sees a '/' character. So, if I have a path: '/posts/type/my-type/hello-world/yes', the match still shows true. Or if I have a slash at the end of the path (/posts/type/my-type/), `my-type/` gets matched.

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpwbxK?editors=001

Weirdly, when I set the same regular expression in PHP, everything is fine but I think that is because in PHP, I need to escape all the slashes inside the regular expression.

Comment: `var regexp = new RegExp('^' + regroute + '/?$');`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, i suggest to post this as an answer, else i will

Comment: @AvinashRaj I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `regroute` to the following so that it will stop at `/`:

```
var regroute = route.replace(/\:[a-zA-Z]+/, '([^\/]*)');
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqRPYJ

Comment: Even though I wanted to go with my previous idea I like this one better, mainly because it allows me to match multiple variables in a route. Thank you!

Comment: @Karthik: A monthly record! :) Congrats! Do you sleep at all? :)

Comment: Congrats both of you. You two people are doing my work now.. :-)

Comment: @stribizhev thank you and congrats to you too.. and yes I sleep `8-9` hrs a day :P .. btw.. whats a monthly record? :O

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Do not forget there are vks, hwnd, Fede, Casimir et Hippolyte, etc. Karthik, I meant the reputation on the Activity tab in your profile :)